# SQL Server query start end times

Tags: sql-server, performance, response-time

How can I get the temporal moments delimiting starting and ending an SQL query in SQL Server? If I set statistics time on, is there any way of adding the resulting cpu / elapsed time to the current datetime?

Thanks

Comment: Generate an actual execution plan by running the query in our free tool, [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/). No fiddling with any `SET` commands - it's all just done for you automatically.

Comment: Belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

1) SQL Trace (including SQL Profiler) to intercept { SP:StmtCompleted | SP:StmtCompleted } with with following columns CPU time, Duration/Elapsed time, Starting & Ending time of every query

[image]

or

2) Extended events sessions (SQL2008+)

In both cases, these events (`%:StmtCompleted`) could have a negative impact on server performance so don't use this methods on a heavy used server (production). If you have performance problems on a production server this could aggravate the problem.

3) Instead, if you want to detected those { queries / sql modules } with performance problems you could use

SQL2005+ [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx)

SQL2008+ [sys.dm_exec_proc_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701(v=sql.100).aspx)

SQL2008+ [sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280646(v=sql.100).aspx)

Example:

```
SELECT TOP(50) ... 
    total_worker_time *1.00 / execution_count AS Avg_CPU_time,
    total_elapsed_time *1.00 / execution_count AS Avg_Duration,
    total_logical_reads *1.00 / execution_count AS Avg_LIO_time
FROM sys.dm_..._stats 
ORDER BY Avg_LIO_time DESC
```

You could use Glenn Berry's scripts 
http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-november-2013/